# Blank page when trying to add new content

Tags: 7, wsod

I've to cope with something very odd: I can't add any type of content anymore. For example: when I go to Content > Add content > Article, I navigate correctly to the 'add acticle' page, but I simply get a white screen. I didn't have this before and I can't remember installing new modules. I already tried to flush all caches, but that didn't solve anything. Even when I add

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
?>
```

to my index.php or settings.php file, no erros are displayed. Please help!

Edit 1: going to the Configuration screen doesn't result in a WSOD. There's only a white screen when I try to add content.

Edit 2: I discovered that I also get a WSOD when I try to edit already existing content. Please help me! I really can't do anything anymore!

Comment: Is there any information in `admin/reports/dblog`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to see the error messages when I get the white screen of death?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/how-to-see-the-error-messages-when-i-get-the-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: Do you have to option to go to the URL of the /configuration? or does it show a WSOD on every page no mather where what you type in the adressbar.

Comment: On which environment runs your Drupal website (Windows, Apache, MySql, PHP)? You can check the log files to see what causes the WSOD (if it is a WAMP stack, i.e.: c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log). I remember that a particular version of PHP (4.3.10) was causing a WSOD ...

Comment: Ok, create manually the log file in the directory "C:/wamp/www/memopoezie/", named apache_error.log. And retry to add content. If it is PHP error, it will be logged in that file.

Comment: I created a log file like you said @MikeVranckx, but nothing appeared in the file after I tried to add new content. So apparently, it's not a PHP error.

Comment: To be sure, can you restart your Apache server and retry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was something wrong with my database. I had to delete it and reinstall my backup.

Answer (score 0):

Open your "settings.php" file and add the following at the top:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
?>
```

Update your question to include the errors that show up when you get the white screen.

Comment: Don't you mean index.php? This a good guide for debugging "White Screen of Death" or WSOD: https://drupal.org/node/158043

Comment: Following your link @KariKääriäinen, I added the code to my index.php file, but after I flushed caches and tried to add a certain content type, no error messages were displayed. I just got exactly the same white screen as before...

Comment: Your best bet is to keep going through that list. It's loooong, I know ;)

Comment: @KariKääriäinen I'm sure index.php works as well, but I'm not sure there's a reason to NOT put it in settings.php  from what I can see, both are valid, and recommendations are split regarding where to include it.  I would argue that it makes more sense to include in settings.php,  since index.php contains no user configurable parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize it could work in settings.php equally well. After a short research it looks like the best location can depend on the problem. I would try index.php at least to start with.

Comment: In my case, it doesn't matter whether I paste the code in the settings.php or index.php file: in both cases there are no error messages when I try to add/edit content (even after clearing my caches first). This is so frustrating!