# Getting WSOD, can't view any errors even after editing index.php

Tags: wsod

I've tried entering:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

at the beginning of my index.php file (after begin php tag and it hasn't done anything.  When I run cron, it comes back and tells me that everything is ok.

Here's a brief overview of things that have transpired today:

- I updated my views modules and made a database backup (i have no idea
  how to restore from this, btw)
- I updated to core .24
- I ran cron andfixed errors concerning .htaccess files. I followed this tutorial:
  https://drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003
- I turned off error reporting (cause it's a production server: www.jcoledesign.com is the address)
- All hell broke loose.  At first it stopped loading some images, then it stopped loading all CSS, this is likely due to caching
- I added the above code to my index.php file
- I cleared cache, went back and tried to replace my .htdocs files with something more simplistic and still no go.

  I'm running out of ideas and nothing I try from here or google seems to work.

Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you also run the update.php?

Comment: Related: [How to see the error messages when I get the white screen of death?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/how-to-see-the-error-messages-when-i-get-the-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: Too many things changed at a time. Can you tell us exactly between which steps site stopped working? I guess turning error reporting off wasn't the trigger and it must have happened earlier? Can you restore from backup and then try, testing step by step? And can you access server's error.log ?

Comment: When I try to run update.php it just gives me a blank screen.  I'm guessing that it's something to do with a server call.

Comment: I'm guessing that messing with the htaccess files is what screwed it up, cause it seemed like it stopped uncaching things afterwords.  I had a WSOD problem earlier when I first installed and a server admin from my hosting company said he fixed it by changing my htaccess files.  I reviewed some of the changes he made and it looks like he just added          

SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006       

and commented out Options +FollowSymLinks   I tried remaking these changes but it was to no avail.

Comment: Also, after I updated the core to 7.24, I did ran update.php and it noticed that I needed to update the image module.  I did that shortly before running cron and trying to fix the HTACCESS issues. I didn't notice anything not caching after I did this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

The .htaccess file in sites/defaults/files/  **CAN NOT** include `Deny from all`

The [tutorial](https://drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003) I referenced earlier mentioned that /temp/.htaccess should have this included, but it didn't say that if you included it in other files that it would crash your site.

*As a side note: It would be great if there was a basic tutorial out there for .htaccess files so that I can get an understanding of everything that's going on here without having to spend months/years learning everything else associated with hosting a drupal website completely inside and out.*

Comment: There are tutorials on htaccess files all right. My google search results: [1](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml) [2](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/htaccess/) [3](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) [4](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files/) (randomized order).

Comment: I just found out the same issue. It was because some of my theming files are located in sites/default/files. So most of the css stopped working. After removing 'Deny from all' from the .htacess everything went back to normal. Now, is it mandatory to have 'Deny from all' to get on the safe side?

Comment: Yes, you should have it in /temp/.htaccess  , but apparently not in /defaults/files/ since it kills everything.