# White screen appears when viewing huge number of nodes as view result

Tags: views, entities, nodes, panels, wsod

I have a View which display fields of nodes. I have to display all of the items. I cannot introduce a Pager.

There are approximately 4000 nodes as the result of the view. The View preview works perfectly fine, i.e all 4000 nodes are displayed, in the View preview result.

Placing the View on a panel page and loading the page gives the "White screen of death".

What could be the problem?

Comment: First, see this question about debugging WSOD: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/how-to-see-the-error-messages-when-i-get-the-white-screen-of-death . Second: most likely cause is that PHP exceeded maximum excution time.

Comment: Is there any other way to make this work without changing the maximum execution time on server.

Comment: @neetumorwani Not if you want to use Views, no - it does what it does, if you haven't got enough memory you need more memory, or you need to reduce the size of the query results. Try limiting to 500, then 1000, then 1500, and so on until you find out where it's cracking. That'll be your current per-page limit. All of that assumes that the problem is definitely lack of memory, you'd need to check your server logs to confirm that first

Comment: @Clive This page-> admin/reports/dblog shows no error logs related to maximum execution time. The only log which i see is- SPI update server response messages: SPI data processing has been queued. Not sure what does this mean.

Comment: @neetumorwani _Server_ logs, not Drupal logs (Apache, nginx, fpm, whatever makes sense for your setup)

Comment: Views usually loads each node object to fetch field data for them. You could possibly get away with implementing your own Views classes which only fetch what you need, but they won't likely work with Views extension modules expecting a full node.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try use this module [View Infinite Scroll](https://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) to try stagger the amount of results returned by Views in one go? This would help the web server from running out of memory returning 4000 results in one go, but is better UX wise than implementing a pager.