# I get a white screen with nothing in the source when i update a content type to include a location

Tags: wsod

So I have a site running drupal 7, i have a content type called seminar... inside that content type I have a form field for location to be added, but not required(if required would never save) So I can create seminars just fine but if i make one with a location or edit a seminar and adda location... upon clicking the save button i get refreshed to a black page with same url but nothing in the source code, error 500 internal server error.

I'm not sure where in my phpMyAdmin this info gets stored, I that could be my error location but just wanted to see if anyone has had a similar encounter with what I am going through now.

Comment: Are you using location module for the location field?

Comment: I'm guessing the issue isn't related to data storage, but PHP code that the location field depends upon (e.g. a missing geocoding library). See the post, [How to see the error messages when I get the white screen of death?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/how-to-see-the-error-messages-when-i-get-the-white-screen-of-death?rq=1) for info about where the PHP code is failing. It will point you in the direction of what is going wrong.