# Error while adding any field in custom content type

Tags: 7, database, wsod

I am unable to add any field in my custom content type, when I click on save button or click on upload after adding images it gives me the following error and for the text field the error is simply `Exception thrown without a stack frame in unknown on lne 0`, after this a white screen appears. :
[image]

After this website appears to be blank until I import the database again. 
**UPDATED**
After adding following lines of code in the bottom of `settings.php`,

```
error_reporting(-1);  // Have PHP complain about absolutely everything 
$conf['error_level'] = 2;  // Show all messages on your screen, 2 =   ERROR_REPORTING_DISPLAY_ALL.
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);  // These lines just give you content on WSOD pages.
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

I got the errors appears instead of white screen:
[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like your web server is returning any data on the AJAX request for uploading. Does your Drupal logs report any PHP errors?

Comment: @Shawn, in recent log messages there is a php warning `Warning: array_flip() [function.array-flip]: `, I dont know what is this but really confused why I cant upload more than one image in my custom content type

Comment: That's likely not the problem. Warnings don't completely stop page execution.

Comment: Actually not only image field, I am unable to add any field :(

Comment: When you say "After this website appears to be blank until I import the database again.", you mean you get a white screen on any page you load after the error, even the home page?

Comment: yes @shawn white screen

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/how-to-see-the-error-messages-when-i-get-the-white-screen-of-death?lq=1) to see what error that pops up after a field save crashes the site. An `AJAX http request terminated abnormally` error is so broad you'll never find a good answer.

Comment: I have got the solution, by changing `max_allowed_packet` in `wamp>my.ini` from `1m` to `16m`. It works for me.

Comment: Thanku So much @Shawn for helping me out, I have posted my answer :)