# How to add an 'if' statement for a content type in a custom views-view.tpl.php?

Tags: views, theming, nodes

Is it possible to add an 'if' statement for a content type in a custom `views-view.tpl.php`?

This is just so I can add text to show if the post in the view is either an 'episode' or an 'announcement'. The content type is called announcement.

I want to do this because I need to identify and style differently based on the post type:

- If it's from an episode, it displays the episode number.
- If it's an announcement, it says announcement.

So basically something like so:

```
<?php if (content_type='whatever') {... code goes here ...} ?>
```

If this is possible, can you provide an example?

**Note**: I have a custom theme called `views-view-field--first-post--block--created.tpl.php` and all it has is `<?php print $output; ?>`. It's called a field content date.

Also, this is what the output of the entire view looks like: `stdClass Object ( [node_created] => 1434783086 [node_title] => CTRL Daily Episode 11 [nid] => 11 [node_type] => ctrl_daily )`. [node_type] is what I want.

Comment: yes, but why would you have a function called if()?

Comment: To identify and style differently based on the post type. If it's from an episode , it displays the episode number. If it's an announcement, it says announcement. <?php if (content_type='whatever' {?>code goes here<?php } ?>

Comment: oh, an IF statement... you asked about an if function... entirely different things. The answer is still yes

Comment: Can you give an example? Cannot find help on this topic. And it's for a view.

Comment: all you asked was whether or not it was possible, and it is. How to implement it really requires more information. Do you want it act on the entire view, on a row, on a field, etc. you need to edit the question and elaborate

Comment: I have a custom theme called `views-view-field--first-post--block--created.tpl.php` and all it has is `<?php print $output; ?>`. It's called a field content date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25353/discussion-between-gregory-schultz-and-geoff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving your own code a bit, it'd be better to not set the dummy variable, since you probably won't use it again. To make it a bit cleaner:

```
<?php if ($row->node_type === 'announcements'): ?>
  <?php // This shows up for node->type of announcement. ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php // Everything else. ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note that it's usually more readable (and thus considered best practice) to use alternative control syntax when in a view.

For additional smart checking, you should probably create a check to make sure that the node_type property is set on the $row object before checking it...

```
<?php if (isset($row->node_type) && $row->node_type === 'announcements'): ?>
  <?php // This shows up for node->type of announcement. ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php // Everything else. ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it by adding `Node Type` field to views and access it using `$row` variable in `views-view.tpl.php`.

```
$rows: The results of the view query, if any
```

Or `$views` is also accessible in each and every views template file.

Comment: Don't understand your answer, please be specific.

Comment: In your template file `print_r($row)`, You will get the fields added in view. So that add a content type, you will get a `$row->[content_type]` object in template file.

Comment: I keep getting white screen when I use this code:
`<?php if($row->[node_type] => 'announcements' ) { ; ?>  
Show
<?php } else { ?>
the rest
<?php } ?>`

Comment: There might be something fatal error. Try enabling error log and display errors on.

Comment: Still get white screen.

Comment: It is the thing that can you debug. Check php's error log file, comment code, change variable.. etc.

Comment: Don't think so, this is an intranet site running MAMP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25354/discussion-between-gregory-schultz-and-sumit-madan).

Comment: It it helps, the output of the view: `stdClass Object ( [node_created] => 1434783086 [node_title] => CTRL Daily Episode 11 [nid] => 11 [node_type] => ctrl_daily )`

Comment: @GregorySchultz You'll need to debug this yourself, it's not possible to do so from here. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/how-to-see-the-error-messages-when-i-get-the-white-screen-of-death for some pointers, and check your error logs. Your MAMP installation does have them (unless you've turned them off, in which case just turn them back on again), you can easily find out where they are with a quick google search

Comment: I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. An if statement doesn't work on [node_type] unless it has something to look at. Give it something to compare it will make it work. Also make sure your using row output on themes template in order for the following code to work.

Example: 
`<?php $value = ($row->node_type) ; ?>
<?php if($value == 'announcements') { ?>
yes
<?php } else { ?>
nope
<?php } ?>`