# Converting Drupal 5 to 6, theme_views_view() error

Tags: views, theming

I'm working in Drupal for the first time and working on migrating a Drupal theme from D5 to D6. There doesn't seem to be ANY documentation for the error or issue and I need some help.  Again, I've never used Drupal, so I'm completely in the dark.

I'm getting the following error on ALL my views pages after the upgrade:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function _views_get_style_plugins() /sites/all/themes/vets/template.php on line 152
```

Removing the function all together from the template.php file, just gives a blank white screen.

Here's the function that is throwing the error:

```
/**
* Customize Views Output
*/
function vets_views_view($view, $type, $nodes, $level = NULL, $args = NULL) {
  $num_nodes = count($nodes);

  if ($type == 'page') {
    drupal_set_title(filter_xss_admin(views_get_title($view, 'page')));
    views_set_breadcrumb($view);
  }

  if ($num_nodes) {
    $output .= views_get_textarea($view, $type, 'header');
  }

  if ($type != 'block' && $view->exposed_filter) {
    $output .= views_theme('views_display_filters', $view);
  }

  $plugins = _views_get_style_plugins();
  $view_type = ($type == 'block') ? $view->block_type : $view->page_type;
  if ($num_nodes || $plugins[$view_type]['even_empty']) {
    if ($level !== NULL) {
      $output .= "<div class='view-summary ". views_css_safe('view-summary-'. $view->name) ."'>". views_theme($plugins[$view_type]['summary_theme'], $view, $type, $level, $nodes, $args) . '</div>';
    }
    else {
      $output .= views_theme($plugins[$view_type]['theme'], $view, $nodes, $type);
    }
    $output .= views_get_textarea($view, $type, 'footer');

    if ($type == 'block' && $view->block_more && $num_nodes >= $view->nodes_per_block) {
      $output .= theme('views_more', $view->real_url);
    }
  }
  else {
    $output .= views_get_textarea($view, $type, 'empty');
  }

  if ($view->use_pager) {
    $output .= theme('pager', '', $view->pager_limit, $view->use_pager - 1);
  }

  if ($output) {
    $output = $output . "\n";
  }
  return $output;
}
```

I can't find documentation about the function, nor the error.

Comment: You have some custom code which is calling an obsolete function (`_views_get_style_plugins`), you need to find out what the Drupal 6 equivalent of that function is and alter the code accordingly (there may not be a direct equivalent as Views changed a lot from 5 to 6). After that, if you're still getting a white screen, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/how-to-see-the-error-messages-when-i-get-the-white-screen-of-death, which has information on how to find out what the real underlying error is. Just a heads up, `views_get_textarea` has also gone

Comment: And so has `views_set_breadcrumb`. If you can describe what that code is supposed to do, someone may be able to help - I think it's quite unlikely this is going to be seen by anyone who knows how Views worked back in Drupal 5, it was a long long time ago, so your best bet would be to think about re-doing it altogether

Comment: @Clive, The problem is that I can't find an equivalent code!  There doesn't appear to be documentation anywhere from it.  Plus, when I add the error reporting, it shows nothing either.

Comment: Yeah you're in an unenviable position here, documentation for code upgrades between Views 5 and 6 will probably never have existed (and if they did they'll be buried somewhere now behind obscure search terms). What I'm saying is that you should forget about that, decide exactly what you want that code to do _now_, and write it from scratch while looking at the docs for Views 6. It's just my personal opinion, but if you don't ignore the Drupal 5 element here I think you're in for a painful journey

Comment: @Clive Thanks... yeah, I think that is what is going to need to happen.  I'm having to edit many of the views, just to see if I can get them to work.  Not working very well... that's for sure.