# Why am I getting redirect to node?destination=node when trying to login?

Tags: users, uri

I just moved my site to another server, and when  I try to login drupal redirects to a blank page. I have no idea
what can I do?
Please, help me. thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

This link might able to help you. 
[How to see the error messages when I get the white screen of death?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/how-to-see-the-error-messages-when-i-get-the-white-screen-of-death)

It might be .htacces problem. Maybe you should ask your hosting provider to help you solve this problem. My hosting provider always help me solve when this problem appear.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have placed your drupal website inside a folder in your webserver root eg. http://example.com/drupal. If that is the case in you .htaccess file uncomment `RewriteBase /drupal` and replace /drupal with name of your drupal root directory.